# how to create subfolders in gitbook build?

Tags: gitbook

I'm using gitbook to create a documentation site. 
I would like to run

```
gitbook build docs dist
```

(docs being the folder where all my *.md files are, and dist- the target folder)

and expect the output to be:

```
dist/index.html
dist/docs-sub-folder/ <all html files>
```

the index.html will serve the content files frmo the docs-sub-folder.
is that possible?

Comment: What are you expecting `index.html` to serve?

Comment: all data-paths are assigned with an html file, that currently sits on the root

Comment: If you want single HTML output, it's [not supported](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook-cli/issues/27).

Comment: no, that's not what I want- I want to control the location of html files